# Pandas Series to json and back

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have some problems converting a simple Pandas Series into a json string and back. Here's my attempt

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.Series(data=[1.0,2.0,3.0],index=[10,20,30])
x = f.to_json()
a = pd.read_json(x)
```

This results in ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an Index.

The json String x looks like
{"10":1.0,"20":2.0,"30":3.0}

What's missing here. Please help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to specify the type of object (default is `DataFrame`) and the format of the JSON string. More info [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html).

This should work:

```
a = pd.read_json(x, typ='series', orient='records')
```

Comment: ah, me being stupid. I oversaw the typ argument... Easy now. Works. Thanks so much